# How to generate authorization signature

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

My application requires the user to grant permission for getting transaction details on their behalf.
I'm using 'PayPal::SDK::Core::Util::OauthSignature' to generate the `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` header but I'm confused by the `url` parameter.

I thought to use the API endpoint for that specific operation, which is `https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails`, but it doesn't seem to work since I'm getting the same `You do not have permission to get these payment details` error.

Comment: It's probably *your* service or application URL. Unless this is hard-coded to your Paypal account details? A quick look at https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/raseshshah/permission-services-apis suggests it could be the callback url . . .

Comment: The problem is not with the permissions service, but with the service I'm calling on behalf of other user using the authorization header.

Comment: BTW, that blog post is less information than the official PayPal documentation: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_permissions.pdf